# Convert image in Mat to BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, opencv

I have this source code which can open image for OpenCv in Mat then do some operation then `bufferedImage` should convert it to image so it can be displayed in JFrame. But I can not figure out how to pass arguments.

```
public class objectDetection{


    public void getMatImg(){

        Mat imageInMat = Imgcodecs.imread(getClass().getResource("lena.png").getPath());
    }

    /*
    *
    *    OpenCV code
    */


    public static BufferedImage bufferedImage(Mat m) {


        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        if (m.channels() > 1) {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        }
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(), m.rows(), type);

        m.get(0, 0, ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData());
        return image;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code we used a while ago for 2.4.8 or .9.  Let me know if it works for you.

I think we may have had some problems with it when we tried to pass in an existing BufferedImage, but it worked fine if you pass in null for the BufferedImage.

```
/**  
 * Converts/writes a Mat into a BufferedImage.  
 *  
 * @param matrix Mat of type CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC1  
 * @return BufferedImage of type TYPE_3BYTE_BGR or TYPE_BYTE_GRAY  
 */  
public static BufferedImage matToBufferedImage(Mat matrix, BufferedImage bimg)
{
    if ( matrix != null ) { 
        int cols = matrix.cols();  
        int rows = matrix.rows();  
        int elemSize = (int)matrix.elemSize();  
        byte[] data = new byte[cols * rows * elemSize];  
        int type;  
        matrix.get(0, 0, data);  
        switch (matrix.channels()) {  
        case 1:  
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;  
            break;  
        case 3:  
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;  
            // bgr to rgb  
            byte b;  
            for(int i=0; i<data.length; i=i+3) {  
                b = data[i];  
                data[i] = data[i+2];  
                data[i+2] = b;  
            }  
            break;  
        default:  
            return null;  
        }  

        // Reuse existing BufferedImage if possible
        if (bimg == null || bimg.getWidth() != cols || bimg.getHeight() != rows || bimg.getType() != type) {
            bimg = new BufferedImage(cols, rows, type);
        }        
        bimg.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, cols, rows, data);
    } else { // mat was null
        bimg = null;
    }
    return bimg;  
}
```